# Updating a QML canvas

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am a QML / Javascript noob, and would like some help with that.

I want to insert some points (represented as small black circles) onto a white QML canvas element and then run an algorithm on them (such as finding convex hulls via an external geometric library)

Here is my QML code.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    id: root
    width: 640 
    height: 480 
    visible: true 

    Canvas {

        width:  1000
        height: 1000

        onPaint: {
            var context = getContext("2d");

        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mymouse
            anchors.fill: parent

            property var arrpoints : []
            onClicked: {

                // Record mouse-position
                arrpoints = arrpoints.concat([mouseX, mouseY])
                console.log(arrpoints)

            } 
        }

    } 
}
```

So far the above code, opens up a window, with a QML canvas on it, and can keep track of the positions on the canvas (via the array `arrpoints`) where I single-clicked with my mouse, and outputs the array of clicked-points to the console.

But now, everytime the `arrpoints` changes, how do I 'tell' QML to draw a small black circle at that point immediately?

I would have thought the `onPaint` part of QML would trigger the rendering of the new state immediately, but it seems that part is only for the initial drawing on the canvas, before the user starts interacting with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the canvas `requestPaint()` function to force the painting. It is also advisable to save the data of the positions appropriately: `{"x": x_value, "y": y_value}`

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    id: root
    width: 640 
    height: 480 
    visible: true 

    Canvas {
        id: canvas

        width:  1000
        height: 1000

        onPaint: {
            var context = getContext("2d")
            context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
            context.lineWidth = 1
            for(var i=0; i < mymouse.arrpoints.length; i++){
                var point = mymouse.arrpoints[i]
                context.ellipse(point["x"]-5, point["y"]-5, 10, 10)
            }
            context.stroke()
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mymouse
            anchors.fill: parent
            property var arrpoints : []
            onClicked: {
                arrpoints.push({"x": mouseX, "y": mouseY})
                canvas.requestPaint()
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```